# How to select only single or multiple consecutive paragraphs inside same and immediate parent

Tags: html, css

I have below HTML structure

```css
 table, th, td {
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    th, td {
      padding: 5px;
    }
```

```html
<body>
    <h1>Contents</h1>
    <main class="parent" contenteditable="true">
        <p>paragraph1</p>
        <p>paragraph2</p>
        <a href="https://www.google.com/">Visit google.com!</a>
        <p>paragraph3</p>
        <table>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <p>paragraph4</p>
                <p>paragraph5</p>
              </td>
              <td>
                <p>paragraph6</p>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <p>paragraph7</p>
                    <p>paragraph8</p>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <p>paragraph9</p>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <p>paragraph10</p>
                    <p>paragraph11</p>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </td>
              <td>
                <p>paragraph12</p>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <p>paragraph13</p>
          <p>paragraph14</p>
    </main>
  </body>
```

I am trying to implement this functionality in a text editor where each paragraph is a DIV element with contenteditable. So in order to select(user select) multiple paragraph, I should make parent as contenteditable.
I should be able to select only consecutive paragraphs inside immediate parent element.

These paragraphs can be present inside main div element or inside table or inside list but at one point of time I should be able to select only consecutive paragraphs inside same parent.

For example either I should able to select paragraph1 and/or paragraph2 inside main section only or paragraph4 and paragraph5 from td element. Could you please suggest me how I can achieve this?

Comment: As I understand it, the other paragraphs are not to be editable (as well as being not selectable). For example paragraph 6 is not editable. Is that correct? (I am trying to understand the blanket 'contenteditable' attribute being set on main but the requirement not to have e.g. paragraph 6 text selectable).

Comment: All the paragraphs are editable irrespective of whether it is present inside main div or td or li element. But once I select consecutive paragraphs inside main div, I should not able to select any other paragraphs present inside td or li and vice versa.

Comment: Different browsers seem to treat what happens with a combination of contenteditable and user-select differently so it seems that a general CSS-based solution is unlikely. I think you will have to resort to Javascript and implementing selection through code.

Comment: It is okay if you suggest a solution combining CSS and javascript.